# Create an IRC Server

Tags: c, irc

I need to develop an *IRC* server, I don't have any idea how to do it. The language that I should use is *C* and maybe *SQL* if it's needed.

Could you provide some insight and help me understand from where I should start?

Note: I have looked for many documentation on Web but nothing clear.

Comment: Start out by learning about client/server applications first, using simple socket communications. There are many tutorials on the net. Then after you feel you have a good grasp on how a multiplexed server should work, then you can study the IRC protocol, and start working on a server for that. Or you simply grab one of the existing servers, and go from there.

Comment: You need to read up on the protocol itself on IETF and then learn socket programming. But answering your question more specifically is very hard!

Comment: thank you for your explication , i have installed Irc serveur and client, I'll try  to use them for some days to understand how it works

Answer (score 2):

look at my old IRC bot: https://github.com/kala13x/derpina (IRC Client)

Every line is commented and documented and I think it will be easy to understand for you.

And look at this too: https://github.com/bloodead/IRC (IRC Server)

Comment: thank you for sharing , I have question about the server, should we manipulate IP adresses in the code ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but you can do everything with IP address, edit, on the fly change and e.t.c.

Comment: I wanted to say , if we need to manipulate adresses to mount the IRC Server